# Static homepage duplicate issue

Tags: homepage, customization

I already made a post on official wordpress forum,but hava no replay to my question.
Also made a search in the forum here and in Google as well but couldn't find solution for my problem.
I'm using CMS theme for my website [foxcleaners.co.uk](http://foxcleaners.co.uk) with static homepage.
The problem is that i have to choose a post which the theme will use as a homepage.OK,i made a post for the homepage and set as noindex,nofollow,but Google has indexed this post!!Also can anyone tell me how Google found this post?There is no links to it.I don't have categories menu on sidebar..?The best solution will be if someone can tell me how to set a unique homepage (without to choose post or page).I love WP but this is huge problem for people like me who wants to use it as CMS system.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the page you linked to, I find no "noindex" or "nofollow" there. And there are links to that... The "Home" on your menu is a link to your homepage is it not? Out of curiosity, why would you want your homepage not to be tracked and listed in google?

Comment: In case however that you want your whole site to be more difficult to find, you can go to Settings => Reading and select the "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" checkbox on the "Search Engine Visibility" option. I hope that helps!

Comment: What are you using to set the `noindex` and `nofollow` robots rules? Unless I have really missed something big, that isn't WordPress Core.

Comment: You missunderstood my questions.Of Course i want my homepage to be indexed.Let me explain again -

Comment: In this theme  (like on most wordpress themes) to have a static homepage,you have to create and trhen choose a post or page.Lets say page: exmaple.com/page .Then when you set  exmaple.com/page to be your homepage,you will end up with same content twice,once will one your homepage - exmaple.com,and then on the page you made to use as a homepage - exmaple.com/page .In the eyes of Google - you have duplicate content,and your site quality is in trouble.So i'm asking if there is a solution to have a static homepage without the need to use other page or post.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite unclear, that's probably why you are getting inconsistent answers.

If you want Google not to follow you (or any search website), you could use, as recommend by WPMU-DEV Ari, "Search Engine Visibility" which can be found in the Settings -> Reading menu. However remember, search engines are not forced to listen and/or obey your request.

From the comments I am getting that you believe www.site.com and www.site.com/home are both indexes and displayed on search engines? And your trying to avoid this?
This is not completely true; if you pick a page as your static home page it will not be shown as a duplicate on Google. There are two reasons for this;

1. Wordpress will automatically take care of this 'duplicate' issue for you.
2. If two duplicates would exist Google will filter it out for you (due to the automatic redirect, and duplicate content).

Also if it would occur, users will actually never realize it due to the redirect. (Just try going to www.site.com/home and you will see it will automatically redirect you to www.site.com.)

If this is not what your looking for, you could also create your own static page by creating a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) and setting this as your static page. Or create a custom page and redirect your domain to this page, instead of WordPress's Index.

---

In regards to the question: "how Google found this post?". I am not finding any `nofollow` or `noindex` on your website. And there are quite a bit of links available on the page and your site.

A more general info-video on how Google works can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyCYyoGusqs).
Hope this answers your question, if not please rephrase and elaborate a bit more on what your actually looking for.